# Virtuoso unicode issue

Tags: unicode, virtuoso

I got an issue with virtuoso on dbpedia server:

```
select distinct ?wt
where {
?wt rdfs:label "Concerto"@fr .
}
```

return `http://dbpedia.org/resource/Concerto`

```
select distinct ?wt
where {
?wt rdfs:label "Opéra"@fr .
}
```

return `http://dbpedia.org/resource/Opéra`

```
select distinct ?wt
where {
values ?ope {"Opéra"@fr}
?wt rdfs:label ?ope .
}
```

also return `http://dbpedia.org/resource/Opéra`, but

```
select distinct ?wt
where {
values ?ope {"Opéra"@fr "Concerto"@fr}
?wt rdfs:label ?ope .
}
```

only return `http://dbpedia.org/resource/Concerto`

In fact when I use values only non unicodes queries match if more than one value is given.

Comment: The queries you say return [`http://dbpedia.org/resource/Opéra`](http://dbpedia.org/resource/Op%C3%A9ra), **_actually_** return the unaccented [`http://dbpedia.org/resource/Opera`](http://dbpedia.org/resource/Opera). Your issue may actually be with the DBpedia data…

Comment: Also note that DBpedia-specific issues are often more quickly resolved via the [DBpedia mailing list](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/dbpedia-discussion); and Virtuoso-specific issues via the [Virtuoso Users mailing list](http://sourceforge.net/p/virtuoso/mailman/virtuoso-users/) or the [OpenLink Support Forums](http://boards.openlinksw.com/support/index.php). (ObDisclaimer: I work for OpenLink Software, maker of Virtuoso.)